# How to reset or reuse InputStream after getting its format

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to re-read(reset) an `InputStream` that holds an image after reading its format.

I need to write it into a mysql database after reading its format.

It seems that once I read the format, the `InputStream` has no `ImageReaders` again or something. Or perhaps the read operation closes it?

It is an `InputStream` from ServletFileUpload's `FileItem.getInputStream`

Here is the code that reads the image format:

```
  public static String getImageFormat(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
     ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(inputStream);


      Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);

    String extension = null;
      while (readers.hasNext()) {
        ImageReader read = readers.next();

        extension = read.getFormatName(); 
      }
 extension = extension.toLowerCase();
       switch(extension){
                  case "jpeg":
                      extension = "jpg";
                      break;
                  case "jpg":
                      extension = "jpg";
                      break;
                  case "png":
                      extension = "png";
                      break;
                  case "gif":
                      extension = "gif";
                      break;
                  case "bmp":
                      extension = "bmp";
                      break;
                  default:

              }
       return extension;
  }
```

Once `getImageFormat` is called, even ImageIO.read(inpustream) cannot read the image again.

What do I do to the `InputStream` after passing it to `getImageFormat` in order to be able to write its data to the database?

**EDIT**

All of these occur in a Java Servlet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser should set a content-type header to tell you what format the image is in, or a filename in some other header. You shouldn't have to examine the image yourself.

BUT if you must, wrap a `BufferedInputStream` around it, call `mark(4096)` or whatever the `ImageIO` reader reads from it, do the `ImageIO`, and then call `reset()` to put it back where it was. If `ImageIO` reads more than you thought, `reset()` will throw an exception, so you can fine tune it.

Comment: Does the browser set it by default or do I set it myself?

Comment: Also, how do I know what the ImageIO read from it, when I only determined the format name, I didnt read the data in the inputsream per se.

Comment: The browser sets it if you're doing a file upload via HTML. If your client isn't a browser, you set it. Make it agree with whatever the browser does for a file upload. Re the number, just see if `reset()` threw an exception. If it didn't, your number is OK.

Comment: If I may ask, why does the InputStream become unusable after calling the getImageFormat method when I have not read any data from it? Does passing it to ImageIO#ImageInputStream() somehow destroy it?

Comment: Because `ImageIO` reads from it, to determine the image type. So when you use the same input stream to store the image, the beginning has been lost.